# Jest setup config not working on Bitbucket

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest, bitbucket-pipelines

I have this error on my bitbucket pipelines when trying to run Jest Unit Tests.

```
    Validation Error:
    Module ..\test\EnvironmentalVars.ts in the setupFiles option was not found.
         <rootDir> is: /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/main
```

Jest Config:

```
"setupFiles": [
            "..\\test\\EnvironmentalVars.ts"
        ]

also tried:

"setupFiles": [
            "<rootdir>\\test\\EnvironmentalVars.ts"
        ]
```

- The file does exist.
- I have tried using the < rootdir> tag as well, no luck.
- I have tried with forward and backward slashes just for sanity sake.
- **This works locally with no issues.**

Answer (score 0):

When you tried forward slashes, was it one slash or double slashes? Because you don't need to escape forward slashes, and you would need to change it to `/` for it to work on Linux.

```
"setupFiles": [
    "../test/EnvironmentalVars.ts"
]
```

Also try

```
"setupFiles": [
    "$BITBUCKET_WORKSPACE/test/EnvironmentalVars.ts"
]
```

`$BITBUCKET_WORKSPACE` is the path your repo gets checked out to. So if the relative path is correct, this should point to the correct file.